# Best and possible device specs for high speed 3d plotter

Tags: arduino, motor, stepper-motor, servo, 3d

This is my first post here and I want to ask you simply about one problem at creating 3d plotter.

My goal is to create a 3D pen plotter with Arduino, but I want that this is as fast as possible and as exact as possible at the same time without very big costs. Is it possible that pen draws 0,1 mm² dot to some location in 1 microsecond (other platforms do better times, so maybe they have to be used) and then do this same again at some other location on the paper?

I want to do as small dots as possible including these criteria.

Finally which (DC) motor type is the best for my purposes (servo, stepper or normal)?
Normal motors are fast but not so exactly, but if I time it to run very exactly or does the norm throw the movement values ​​of the motors too much? Servo motors are intermediate form and steppers are very exact but very slow to my knowledge.

Comment: Fast / exact / cheap. Pick any two. You mention paper and 3D with no explanation. You also haven't given any idea of the X and Y (and Z?) stroke.

Comment: This is still in the design phase, but it should also have a z-stroke and the size would be roughly the size of a regular 3d printer.

Comment: It seems to me that you've gone into design phase but skipped the specification stage which would be the first thing to do. For a 250 mm drive axis you're going to need a screw or a belt drive and will have to address backlash, repeatability, etc.

Comment: There are a lot of different tutorials on the internet, so I'm just going to make based on them and change only enough to make the things I want happen - I don't spend a lot of time for the designing I just vision it in my head and then build it.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what is a “3D pen plotter”?

Comment: Like a 3d printer, but has a pencil and draws and writes to a paper (Look from Google).

Comment: @DoctorThumb a sheet of paper is 2D ... why do you require the third axis?

Comment: `dot to some location in 1 microsecond` ... that would be faster than a bullet

Comment: @jsotola I want to draw manyy dots on top of the lower dots, that's why I need also the third stroke. Also: Why someone can't just reopen this question? Okay, I agree that there is too many text etc. But let's speak simplify: That's just 1 question with some subthings: How to do super fast, exact and cheap 3d pen plotter.

Comment: `Why someone can't just reopen this question?` ... because your post is unfocused ... you ask multiple unrelated questions in your post

Comment: But that's mad! I'm not allowed to open the question again because it needs to be more specific, although on the contrary I'm telling so much precisely so that and just because people can better understand why and what I need the information I'm asking for? This is simply impossible to simplify, or suggest a better question formulation yourself.

Comment: Aren't there a lot of questions that arise in these comments, that why do I want to know such things without this formulation of mine, there would be even more of these comments.

Comment: Okay, sorry, now that I look more closely, I could remove a couple of points, but then would I have to make questions for them separately - that would be too cumbersome.